# Xcart Search Module issue

Tags: php, x-cart

I am facing this syntax error in my search module. Can someone please look into this that what's exact issue.

```
// This is the path to the fts_instant_product_search.php file you uploaded.
{php}$x=parse_url($GLOBALS['smarty']->_tpl_vars['current_location']);$GLOBALS['smarty']->assign('searchPath',$x['path']);{/php}
searchPath = "{$searchPath}/";
```

It produces this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in
>   template
>   "/home/noveltie/public_html/xcart475/skin/lumino_responsive/customer/fts_instant_product_search.tpl"
>   on line 79
>   "{php}$x=parse_url($GLOBALS['smarty']->_tpl_vars['current_location']);$GLOBALS['smarty']->assign('searchPath',$x['path']);{/php}"
>   unknown tag "php" <--   thrown in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/xcart475/include/lib/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 79

Answer (score 1):

X-Cart 4.7.5 uses Smarty version 3.1, which does not allow {php} tag:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

> **IMPORTANT NOTICE**
>
> {php} tags are deprecated from Smarty, and should not be used. 
>   Put your PHP logic in PHP scripts or plugin functions instead.
>
> As of Smarty 3.1 the {php} tags are only available from [SmartyBC](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl).

Your options are:

1. Contact the skin developer and ask them to change the skin's code, so it would be compliant with smarty 3.1
2. Install aforementioned backward compatibility wrapper from here:
   http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl